# Changing position of setCustomValidity warning in CSS

Tags: html, css

Below is part of my CSS code for HTML. I want all the inputs to be filled when the button "register" is pressed. If I don't have an address, a little pop-up warning comes right up to the input field. I would like the same with a drop-down menu. I know the code gives you the warning when the button "register" is pressed because of the JavaScript code. But I am wondering: is it possible to change the location of that warning from the "register" button to the drop-down menu?

Thank you for all your help.

```
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div class="container">
        <form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action=".">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="adress" class="form-text">Adress</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adress" placeholder="Rainbow 3" name="adress" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-8" style="height:70px">
                <label for="inputState" class="form-text">State</label>
                <select id="inputState" class="form-control"  name="state" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="0"></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        <div>
        <button href="/oglasi/" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button" aria-pressed="true" onclick="check(this)">Register</button>
        </div>
        <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                function check(input) {
                    if (document.getElementById('inputState').value == "0") {
                        input.setCustomValidity('Choose state.');
                    } else {
                        // input is valid -- reset the error message
                        input.setCustomValidity('');
                            }
                    }
        </script>
        <br>
    </form>
    </div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're calling `setCustomValidity` on the submit button so of course the warning is going to appear there.

Answer (score 0):

you need `setCustomValidity` to select element

```
function check(input) {
   const inputStateElm = document.getElementById('inputState');
   if (inputStateElm.value == "0") {
            inputStateElm.setCustomValidity('Choose state.');
          } else {
            // input is valid -- reset the error message
            input.setCustomValidity('');
          }
        }
```

--

**Full code**

```html
<html lang="en">

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" role="form" method="post" action=".">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="adress" class="form-text">Adress</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="adress" placeholder="Rainbow 3" name="adress" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
          <div class="form-group col-md-8" style="height:70px">
            <label for="inputState" class="form-text">State</label>
            <select id="inputState" class="form-control" name="state" required>
                     <option selected disabled value="0"></option>
                    <option value="1">1</option>
                    <option value="2">2</option>
                    <option value="3">3</option>
                </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button href="/oglasi/" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" role="button" aria-pressed="true" onclick="check(this)">Register</button>
          </div>
          <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            function check(input) {
              const inputStateElm = document.getElementById('inputState');
              if (inputStateElm.value == "0") {
                debugger;
                inputStateElm.setCustomValidity('Choose state.');
              } else {
                // input is valid -- reset the error message
                input.setCustomValidity('');
              }
            }

          </script>
          <br>
      </form>
      </div>
  </body>

</html>
```